# Angular ag-Grid - onSortChanged - stop the datasource request

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I used ag-grid with rowModelType: 'infinite'

When I made a request of the sort, filter, or change page, the system runs the getRows of dataSource

I need to check the sort request ( or filter ) before run getRows and stop the execution.

```
onSortChanged: () => {
  if (something) {
    // continue with sort and execute getRows ...
  } else {
    // stop with sort and NOT execute getRows...
  }
};
```